# Python 3 "Using variable before assignment" but only in 1 of 2 functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tkinter, listbox

I have a very strange error. First of all, my code (neverything, of course):

```
import os
import tkinter

frame = tkinter.Frame(main)


listbox = tkinter.Listbox(frame, height=23)
for name in files:
    listbox.insert('end', name)


def play():
    list_element = listbox.get(0,'end')
    list_selection = listbox.curselection()
    selected_element = list()
    for list_index in list_selection:
        selected_element.append(list_element[int(list_index)])

def openfolder():
    list_element = listbox.get(0,'end')         #here I get the error
    list_selection = listbox.curselection()
    selected_element = list()
    for list_index in list_selection:
        selected_element.append(list_element[int(list_index)])
```

I have a listbox (tkinter) and it displays files/folders. I need the

```
list_element = listbox.get(0,'end')         
    list_selection = listbox.curselection()
    selected_element = list()
    for list_index in list_selection:
        selected_element.append(list_element[int(list_index)])
```

block to get the selected file/folder as selected_element[0]. In the first function play() everything works fine. But in the second function openfolder() I get the error "Using variable listbox before assignment", but it is the same code as in play (I copied it).

When I use "global listbox", the selected_element is empty (when I print it, it displays: "[]", when I try to print selected_element[0], I get the error "list index out of range") [yes, I selected a folder].

Is there any way to fix this? I have no idea what is the difference, in play() it works perfectly.

I call this functions with buttons (tkinter) btw.

Thank you very much

My whole code: https://pastebin.com/Tf01Ei2d

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell why this error is happening, since you did not post how you are actually calling these methods.

However, within the methods `play()` and `openfolder()`, the variable `listbox` is unknown since you did not declare it anywhere **within the scope of the method**. So the easiest way would probably be to hand over your `listbox` as parameter to both methods:

```
def play(listbox):
   <algorithm>

def openfolder(listbox):
   <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I just had to delte the listbox (listbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)) instead of creating a new one on top of it (listbox = tkinter.Listbox(frame, height=23)).